# Error in pushing Discord bot to Heroku: Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am having trouble pushing changes that I have made to my Discord bot to heroku.

I have updated my node to version 12.18.2 and my Discord.js to version 12 after I have done this I tried to push the changes to Heroku but Heroku keeps on rejecting my push. I am not sure what the problem exactly is.

My Heroku log:

````
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.18.2...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.5
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules is checked into source control and cannot be cached
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
       Rebuilding any native modules
       
       > ffmpeg-binaries@4.0.0 install /tmp/build_71e019d8/node_modules/ffmpeg-binaries
       > node install
       
       internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
         throw err;
         ^
       
       Error: Cannot find module '/tmp/build_71e019d8/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native/binding-v3.0.8-node-v72-linux-x64/lzma_native.node'
       Require stack:
       - /tmp/build_71e019d8/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native/index.js
       - /tmp/build_71e019d8/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/index.js
       - /tmp/build_71e019d8/node_modules/ffmpeg-binaries/install.js
           at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
           at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
           at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
           at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
           at /tmp/build_71e019d8/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native/index.js:13:14
           at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_71e019d8/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native/index.js:597:3)
           at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
           at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
           at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
           at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14) {
         code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
         requireStack: [
           '/tmp/build_71e019d8/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/node_modules/lzma-native/index.js',
           '/tmp/build_71e019d8/node_modules/decompress-tarxz/index.js',
           '/tmp/build_71e019d8/node_modules/ffmpeg-binaries/install.js'
         ]
       }
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno 1
       npm ERR! ffmpeg-binaries@4.0.0 install: `node install`
       npm ERR! Exit status 1
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the ffmpeg-binaries@4.0.0 install script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.7XYhs/_logs/2020-07-16T19_21_22_644Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - node_modules checked into source control
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#only-git-the-important-bits
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       - A module may be missing from 'dependencies' in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#ensure-you-aren-t-relying-on-untracked-dependencies
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed```
````

Comment: You should try to run a quick `npm update` on your local console.

Comment: I want to stay on my current node 12 version though?

Comment: It will not change.

Comment: I did run **npm update** then I ran the command **audit fix** then it asked me to do **npm install -g npm**

I did those steps then I tried to push it to heroku and heroku still rejected my push. My log

I cant type out my log here so I uploaded my log to hastebin.com

https://hastebin.com/sahojubica.sql

Comment: may I ask why you need the ffmpeg-binaries module ?

Comment: no particular reason.